# A proper gallery in wordpress?

Tags: gallery

The dad from a friend of mine photographs bird feathers for hobby. He has about 6000 of them. I've been asked to find him an easy to use gallery, which should allow some kind of batch processing as it's a lot of photos. I've started off on Gallery2, but we're not on speaking terms anymore; what a piece of shit.

Any suggestion of building a gallery in Wordpress? Key features: folders, batch processing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress can do a lot with images provided it's configured right, and exactly how you want it.
http://ottopress.com/2011/photo-gallery-primer/ will give you the basics to then customise to your requirements.

A great example of this kind of thing can be seen on Matt Mullenweg's site: http://ma.tt/gallery/